# how to automatically find the sum of few fields and save it in another field in DJANGO?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

```
class EmployeeRating(models.Model):
    rating_1 = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    rating_2 = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    rating_3 = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    rating_4 = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    rating_4 = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    total = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

Using a Model Form to take the values, automatically assign values to 'total'.

Comment: Any reason you can't just work it out in the view after the form is submitted rather than doing it within the form. As in something like rating = form.save(), rating.total = rating.rating_1 + rating.rating_2 etc, rating.save()

Comment: Why are there two fields called `rating_4`?

Comment: This sounds like homework

Answer (score 2):

```
class EmployeeRatingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeRating

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmployeeRatingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['total'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        rating = super(EmployeeRatingForm, self).save(commit=False)
        rating1 = self.cleaned_data['rating_1']
        rating2 = self.cleaned_data['rating_2']
        rating3 = self.cleaned_data['rating_3']
        rating4 = self.cleaned_data['rating_4']

        rating.total = rating1 + rating2 + rating3 + rating4
        rating.save()
```

Comment: Any reason for the `commit=True`? Would it be better to set `commit=False` and let the second `save` call do the actual saving so it doesn't hit the database twice? (And also honor the method's `commit` argument by making the second `save` conditional)

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Don't repeat yourself

It seems like a bad idea to have a field in your model containing the total of some other fields in the same model. It would be all too easy to update one and not the other, leaving the fields inconsistent.

So my suggestion is to drop the `total` field and compute it when you need it.

You can add a method to the `EmployeeRating` model that computes it in Python:

```
class EmployeeRating(models.Model):
    # ...

    @property
    def total_rating(self):
        return self.rating_1 + self.rating_2 + self.rating_3 + self.rating_4
```

And if you need to query on the total, you could use [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra):

```
EmployeeRating.objects.extra(
    where = ['rating_1 + rating_2 + rating_3 + rating_4 > 10'])
```

#### 2. Normalize!

The reason why this is awkward is that your model is not [fully normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If you have multiple ratings attached to an `EmployeeRating` record, the natural way to implement them is to have a separate table. If you did this, your model would look like this:

```
class EmployeeRating(models.Model):
    # ... other fields, e.g. foreign key to Employee model.

class Rating(models.Model):
    employee_rating = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeRating, related_name='ratings')
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    # ... other fields, e.g. who performed the evaluation, or when it was done.
```

and then you can use [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) when you need to get the total:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
EmployeeRating.objects.annotate(total_rating = Sum('ratings__rating'))
```